# JAVA SOCKET realize disconnect after two writes

Tags: java, sockets, server, connection

an app in PC using JAVA io.socket which will sends json to a server device ESP8266on TCP on LAN network

when you are connected and when disconnect sequence is executed from java it self everything is ok .

java is client and device is server , when device cuts the connection (here lets use Hercules on localhost) the java program will not being noticed and when i try to write with outputstreamwriter it dose not trig an exception , exception will be executed after at least two writes to socket after the server is being disconnected and the last two writes which was not being received by server will return success! in java. i have read other programmers use a byte send to see if connection is still alive . the same problem is there too . if i send two write each 20 seconds time in between its going to be 60 seconds before java realize server is disconnected and if i send every 1 second is going to be a lot of ATcommand interrupts for nothing .

here is my code:

```
    public boolean Write(String data){
    System.out.println("StartSending");
    if(TESocket.Connected)
    {

        Thread write = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try
                {
                    outputStreamWriter.write(data);
                    outputStreamWriter.flush();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    TESocket.Connected=false;
                    System.out.println("Faild");
                    System.out.println(e.getCause());
                }
            }
        });
        write.start();

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Not Connected");
        return false;
    }
}
```

The TESocket is class which handles Socket using Runnable and Connected is a static boolean since there is just one socket at a time here is the connect method

```
 public boolean  Connect(){
    Thread connect = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                socket= new Socket("127.0.0.1",Integer.parseInt(port));
                if(socket.isConnected())
                {
                    inputStreamReader  = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
                    outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                    TESocket.Connected=true;
                    System.out.println("Connected");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Faild to Connect");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    connect.start();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(TESocket.Connected)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

how can i be noticed if server is out of reach with immediately after sending the write? or is there eny event for noticing that ? maybe some king of asynchronous socket? like it was in QT (Signal Slot for Disconnect)

Comment: You can't. This is how TCP works.

Comment: Well Solve the Problem , gonna post in a few minuets

Answer (score -1):

well By reading method and setting a timeout solved this problem , thanks to reading some post 
in read if i am still connected and not receiving any data time out will be thrown which bring me back to the first lie of the while loop

if i receive data i will be bigger than zero which reader will read data and flag the rec=true so the disconnect sequence dose not take in place

if i don't receive any data and timeout dose not occurs the rec=false and exception will not be thrown so the program will o to disconnect routine 
setting the timeout to 1 millisecond makes it real-time (proportional to my work) in deadline detection

```
public boolean Read()
{
    if (TESocket.Connected)
    {
        try {
            socket.setSoTimeout(1000);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            System.out.println("Problem Timeout");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Thread read = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int i;
                boolean rec=false;
                while (true)
                {
                    char[] reader = new char[250];
                    try {

                            //while(!inputStreamReader.ready());
                            i=inputStreamReader.read(reader);
                            if(i>0) {
                                System.out.println(reader);
                                rec=true;
                            }
                            // Thread.sleep(2500);
                        if(!rec)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Disconnected");
                            TESocket.Connected=false;
                            inputStreamReader.close();
                            outputStreamWriter.close();
                            socket.close();
                            break;
                        }
                        rec=false;

                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Connected");
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        });
        read.start();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: A read timeout does not solve the problem of an immediate write failure.

Comment: Nor does it indicate a dead connection.

Comment: it dose see the disconnect and set a Boolean value to false . from there i check every time i want to write if that connection is alive or not , this works perfectly for me , i actually passed that part of code ,should probably test it before giving a point down!. better that what you said which was nothing !

Comment: A read timeout does not 'see a disconnect'. There is no disconnect to see. What it sees is no data arriving within the timeout period, and that *incoudes* a disconnect. If there had been a disconnect within the timeout period there wouldn't have been a timeout.